# How to Create Popup Form With Same Location of Other Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have read about `Control.PointToClient` or `Control.PointToScreen` on MSDN.

But how to show another form as same location as `TextBox`when `Button` clicked, if I have this control hierarchy ?

```
+- Form
+--- Panel
+---- Panel
+------ TextBox
+------ Button
```

Comment: There is no TextBox in the picture you've shown.

Comment: I edited my question and delete the image, since it's not relevant to my question, please upvote my question, :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PointToScreen` with an empty point (0, 0) to get the location of the control relative to the screen, then just show the form there (make sure `StartPosition` is `Manual`):

```
Point controlPosition = myTextBox.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
MyForm newForm = new MyForm();
newForm.Location = controlPosition;
newForm.Show(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you show new form as showdialog you need to use :

```
newForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```